# what is the difference between external tables and global temporary tables in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, external-tables, global-temp-tables

I have worked with external tables in oracle, It can be created on a file containing data (with many other conditions). Then, How global temporary tables are different from External tables ?

Answer (score 4):

An external table gets its content from e.g. a CSV file. The database itself does not store any data. Their content is visible to all sessions (=connections) to the server (provided necessary access privileges exists). The data exists independently of the database and is only deleted (or changed) if the file is changed externally (as far as I know Oracle can not write to an external table, only read from it - but I haven't used them for ages, so maybe this changed in Oracle 18 or later)

The data for a temporary table is stored and managed inside the database, but each session keeps its own copy of the data in the table. The data is automatically removed by Oracle when the session is disconnected or if the transaction is ended (depending on the definition of the temporary table). Data in a temporary table never survives a restart of the database server.

Comment: Another potentially big practical difference if you plan to query these things: You cannot build an index on an external table, but you can index a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly an external table is a place holder definition which points to a file somewhere on the OS. These are generally used (not limited to) when you have an external interface sending you data in files. You could either load the data in a normal table using sqlldr OR you could use External tables to point to the file itself, you can simply query the table to read from the file. There are some limitations though like you can not update an external table.

GTT - global temporary tables are used when you want to keep some on the fly information in a table such that it is only visible in the current session. There are good articles on both these tables if you want to go more in detail.

One more thing a GTT table access would be faster as compared to an external table access.